# doctrine schema update for 2 entity managers (different databases)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony 4.4, where I've configured 2 entity managers: [default, migrate].
The "Migrate" manager connects to another mysql database, and I can read entities from there -tested-.

Whenever I try to update my "default" manager schema with

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --em="default"
```

I got the following error:

```
In SchemaException.php line 111:
                                                                
  The table with name 'myProject.document' already exists.
```

*This happend because the "default" manager and the "migrate" manager also have the "document" entity, but in 2 different databases.*

I'd like to update only the "default" manager's schema, and ignoring the "migrate" (which is exists in another database and i'm using as read only from there).

Comment: I would probably recommend proper migrations (doctrine/migrations for example), where you actually write code and could check in which database the changes can occur.

Comment: thank you, the migration thrown error because of the same issue, but meanwhile i found the solution - see on bottom

Answer (score 1):

i've found buried deep inside ;-)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="document", schema="otherDatabaseName")
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 */
class Document extends Base {
```

So your "migrate" manager which uses "document" entity in this case, have to get through the **schema** where you've definied the other database's name.

*schema:update* gonna run properly with or without the *-em* option